# How to iterate through two lists in parallel using auxiliary variable with changing increments?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two lists in `Python`, like this:

```
RG = [30, 30, 30, 50, 50, 50, 70, 70, 80, 80, 80]
EC = [2, 2, 2, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10]
```

and I want to iterate over then with an auxiliar variable, like `i`, because when some condition is met (like EC is different of RG), I want that this iteration go to another element that it's not the next one. Like:

```
for i in ?:
    // code
    if EC != RG:
        i = i + 5;
    // code
```

I already saw [zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel), but I didn't found how to do this using it, because this `function` is an `iterable`.

Comment: `for i in range(zip(RG, EC)): if EC[i] != RG[i]: i=i+5; # code`

Comment: @BlueRineS i got ``TypeError: 'zip' object cannot be interpreted as an integer``

Comment: should be `len(zip...` my bad

Comment: @BlueRineS now I got ``TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()``

Comment: aah, my bad. then do `len(list(zip...`

Comment: @BlueRineS now I got ``TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable``, but kabanus answer helped me. thanks for your attention!

Comment: You forgot the range this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop is not useful if you do not want to iterate a container while jumping indices. In this case a while would be more conducive to your task:

```
i = 0
while i < len(RG):
    # code
    if EC[i] != RG[i]:
        i += 5;
    else: i += 1
    # code
```